# Can we hide version number in control panel for certain user groups?

Tags: control-panel

Usecase: the site I'm building has public registration, the publicly registered users have access to only their own specific entry in the back-end (which makes use of many complex fields, such as Matrix, which is why I'm not trying to put this form on the front-end for them to manage).

While everything else is hidden from them already, it'd be nice to hide the Craft version just to hinder any neer-do-wells from easy bug-hunting and hacking shenanigans.

It'd still be useful to have that info displayed for other admin groups though.

Is that possible?

Comment: Per Brandon's answer, you'd need to do this with custom CSS or JS... To avoid writing your own plugin just for this purpose, you can start with either of these plugins: [Control Panel CSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss), [Control Panel JS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write a plugin that hides it with Javascript. We don’t have any plans to make it customizable.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, makes sense as I suppose it's a pretty custom request :)